# Why ISDATE() function return true for '9966'?

Tags: sql-server

I used the `ISDATE()` Function to check whether a value is a Date. but when i put `9966` or any four digit numeric, the function returns true

1. why it happens like that?
2. what is the best way to check a value whether it is a date?

Comment: Oh... i forgot to tel that im using Microsoft SQL server 2008...

Comment: What is wrong with the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [ISDATE()](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/12/sql-server-validate-field-for-date-datatype-using-function-isdate/) function will not be reliable in some cases. So, you should learn How to [Handle ISDATE() with care](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2007/09/24/handle-isdate-with-care.aspx)

> the values in a ISDATE functions are first casted to datetime

and

> if varchar datatype is used to stored formatted dates (ex YYYYMMDD),
>   to check if it is valid date, you need not only to use ISDATE()
>   function, but also use LEN() function

Answer (score 1):

9966 is implicitly CASTable to datetime because it is 9966 days after 01 Jan 1900

Try this (`0` is 01 Jan 1900)

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 9966, 0)
```